# Getting data of a user that matches the user who created a post

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I apologize for the poorly worded title, I wasn't sure how to word it properly. So I have 2 collections:

User

```
_id:60ccb13a21d65f0c7c4c0690
username: testuser
name: test
```

And Createpost

```
_id:60d80b1305dcc535c4bf111a
postTitle: "test post"
postText: "aaaaa"
postUsername: "testuser"
```

If I wanted to get data of testuser from User displayed on his forum post, what would be the best way to do that? This is what I've tried so far:

```
router.get('/forum', async (req,res)=>res.render('forum', {newPost: await Createpost.find().sort({ date: 'desc'}), 
postUser: await User.find({"username": Createpost.postUsername})}));
```

My attempt was to search in the User collection for a matching username field with the postUsername field from the Createpost collection, and then display it in EJS:

```
<% newPost.forEach(newPost => { %>
    Posted by: <%= newPost.postUsername %> - Name: <%= postUser.name %>
    <%= newPost.postText %>
<% }%>
```

But when I do this, nothing appears on the page and I can't figure out any solutions. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: I used aggregation like suggested in the comments, but the following just results in text that says [object Object] and I'm not sure why:

```
router.get('/forum', async (req,res)=>res.render('forum', {newPost: await Createpost.find().sort({ date: 'desc'}), 
postUser: Createpost.aggregate([{$lookup: { from: "User", localField: "postUsername", foreignField: "username", as: "postUser"}},{$unset: "postUsername"}])}));
```

EJS:

```
<% newPost.forEach(newPost => { %>
    Posted by: <%= newPost.postUsername %> - <%= postUser %>
    <%= newPost.postText %>
<% }%>
```

Comment: The way to do it is to "join" the two collections by the `username` using an aggregation query. See [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the aggregate solution:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

```
Createpost.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
         from: "User", 
         localField: "postUsername", 
         foreignField: "username", 
         as: "postUser"
    }
},
{    
    $unset: "postUsername"
},
{
    $sort: {date: -1}
}  
])
```

Edit: The output data from the aggregate should be like this:

```
[{
    _id: 60d80b1305dcc535c4bf111a,
    postTitle: "test post",
    postText: "aaaaa",
    //postUsername: "testuser", --> removed cuz its dupplicated with the postUser below!
    postUser: {
        _id: 60ccb13a21d65f0c7c4c0690,
        username: "testuser",
        name: "test"
    },
    // ... more detail of the post
}},...
]
```

More:
Now you can render the ejs with just an array newPost

```
router.get('/forum', async (req,res)=>res.render('forum', {
    newPost: await Createpost.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
         from: "User", 
         localField: "postUsername", 
         foreignField: "username", 
         as: "postUser"
    }
},
{    
    $unset: "postUsername"
},
{
    $sort: {data: -1}
}  
]) 
}));
```

Then parse the newPost array to ejs like below:

```
<% newPost.forEach(newPost => { %>
    Posted by: <%=newPost.postUser.username%> - Name: <%= newPost.postUser.name%>
    <%= newPost.postText %>
<% }%>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried this solution, but it seems it doesn't return the newly joined fields as objects so I'm having a hard time using the aggregated data in ejs. Any tips?

Comment: @ChanKim I added more detail on the output. You can re-configure how to parse data in ejs base on it!

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the help, but when I try to use it in EJS it just returns [object Object] and I'm not sure why. I edited my original post if you'd like to see it, thank you so much

Comment: @ChanKim When you do aggregate like above, you just need to send the newPost because now the userPost is embedded in the newPost element. I added more detail bellow to show you how to parse the output to ejs :-)

Comment: @ChanKim It returns [object Object] cuz the aggregate output is an array of objects ;)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help! I tried your solution, and it shows the data from Createpost, but not the data from User. I suspect it's a problem with either the "from:" parameter or with the way I'm trying to retrieve the data with newPost.user.name, but I'm not sure. My user schema is called User.js in VS code but in mongodb it says "users", could this be a problem?

Comment: Yeah, try to change it to users, it might solve your problem ;)